# How to deploying MongoDB for non-DBAs

Tags: mongodb

I would like to deploy MongoDB on a shared network folder. 
As I dont have background as a DBA, appreciate if the community can advise on the simplest way to do this.

Some constraints:
- My organisation has quite strict policies on data privacy so I cant do this via cloud services to external providers.
- We have network folders on servers that everyone has access to which I'm thinking of storing the main database on.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using network folders on servers where everyone has access then change the data storage path of MongoDB in `mongod.conf`:

```
atom /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

Change the `dbPath` to your folder location.

```
storage:
  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb
```